# Baremental Device name case sensitive?

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I ordered a baremental server with upper cases host name, after provisioning, I went to see the device name for that server, the hostnames are converted to lower cases. hence, is the device name case sensitive?

Answer (score 0):

yep for baremetal server the name is changed to lower case

Regards

Comment: so, is it case sensitive if I call from api to that sever?

Comment: what call are you gonna do? basically for all the methods you need to use just the id and for the value of hostname you are gonna see it in lower case like in the portal